# Mounts showing up in Finder even with 'nomount' option in /etc/fstab

Tags: finder, time-machine, catalina, mount, apfs

I have an APFS volume I mount in my home directory for some extra apps, and when I mounted it with `nobrowse` in `/etc/fstab`, it seemed to work fine.

However, after enabling Time Machine, the `nobrowse` option has zero effect, and I have to remount it manually with:

`mount_apfs -t apfs -o nobrowse /dev/disk1s7 /Users/nash/Applications`.

I'm using a 2007 Macbook Pro with the dosdude1 Catalina Patcher. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: It turns out that not even the remount command is working anymore, because it's already mounted with `nobrowse`. Without `nobrowse`, the volume shows up in the Desktop, but with it, it only shows up in Finder. However, I just figured out that either way it isn't being indexed by Spotlight Search for some reason. Now I'm REAL curious...